# Android waking up from sleep mode causes ClientProtocolException for http calls

Tags: android, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, sleep-mode

When the device goes into "sleep" or power saving mode (screen goes black) when you hit the power button to restore the screen, all looks well and functions. However when I attempt to do any HTTP calls (using `DefaultHttpClient`) I get `ClientProtocolException`exceptions. I then have to exit the application and come back in, and everything works fine. I know there is the new URLConnection package available, but the refactor will take sometime. Is there any way to correct this?

Here is a sample of the code that fails, but again, it works just fine until the device sleeps:

```
public JSONObject mediaAmazonUploadAuthParams(String key, String contentType, Boolean publicRead) throws MyException {
    JSONObject authParams = null;
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(getBaseUrl() + "myapi");  
    postMethod.setHeader("SessionToken", mSessionToken);
    int versionCode = Utilities.getVersionCode(GlobalState.getInstance().context);
    String versionName = "0.0.0";
    String clientHeader = "android-0.0.0"; 
    postMethod.setHeader("Client", clientHeader);
    postMethod.setHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json");

    GatekeeperResult result;
    JSONObject postJson = new JSONObject();
    try {
        postJson.put("key", key);
        postJson.put("contentType", contentType);
        postJson.put("publicRead", publicRead);
        String postString = postJson.toString();
        postMethod.setEntity(new StringEntity(postString));
        String response = httpClient.execute(postMethod, responseHandler);
        result = new Result(new JSONObject(response));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Client","mediaAmazonUploadAuthParams(), Error httpClient execute ",e);
        throw new MyException(e);
    }
```

Here is the stack trace I get on failure.

```
05-28 11:36:20.891: E/GatekeeperApiClient(8999): org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
05-28 11:36:20.891: E/GatekeeperApiClient(8999):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:589)
05-28 11:36:20.891: E/GatekeeperApiClient(8999):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:685)
05-28 11:36:20.891: E/GatekeeperApiClient(8999):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:659)
05-28 11:36:20.891: E/GatekeeperApiClient(8999):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:648)
05-28 11:36:20.891: E/GatekeeperApiClient(8999):    at com.invocore.fastfield.gatekeeper.GatekeeperApiClient.mediaAmazonUploadAuthParams(GatekeeperApiClient.java:906)
05-28 11:36:20.891: E/GatekeeperApiClient(8999):    at com.invocore.fastfield.utility.LibraryUtils.saveFormMedia(LibraryUtils.java:156)
05-28 11:36:20.891: E/GatekeeperApiClient(8999):    at com.invocore.fastfield.FormActivity$submitFormResultTask.doInBackground(FormActivity.java:2562)
05-28 11:36:20.891: E/GatekeeperApiClient(8999):    at com.invocore.fastfield.FormActivity$submitFormResultTask.doInBackground(FormActivity.java:1)
05-28 11:36:20.891: E/GatekeeperApiClient(8999):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-28 11:36:20.891: E/GatekeeperApiClient(8999):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-28 11:36:20.891: E/GatekeeperApiClient(8999):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-28 11:36:20.891: E/GatekeeperApiClient(8999):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-28 11:36:20.891: E/GatekeeperApiClient(8999):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-28 11:36:20.891: E/GatekeeperApiClient(8999):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
05-28 11:36:20.891: E/GatekeeperApiClient(8999): Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Received redirect response HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently but no location header
05-28 11:36:20.891: E/GatekeeperApiClient(8999):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectHandler.getLocationURI(DefaultRedirectHandler.java:103)
05-28 11:36:20.891: E/GatekeeperApiClient(8999):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.handleResponse(DefaultRequestDirector.java:944)
05-28 11:36:20.891: E/GatekeeperApiClient(8999):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:491)
05-28 11:36:20.891: E/GatekeeperApiClient(8999):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:587)
05-28 11:36:20.891: E/GatekeeperApiClient(8999):    ... 13 more
```

NOTE: This does not happen on only the screen going to sleep...also is a factor of time (over 10 minutes idle). Think it may be related to something getting pulled form memory because of idleness? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post the complete StackTrace..! And have you re-produced this exception on multiple devices ?

Comment: Seems to happen across devices. I'll try and get a stack trace, but it is elusive...today it is not throwing the error, whereas yesterday it was happening consistently.

Comment: Just updated with stack trace...guess next step will be to print out contents of JSON and other goodies...

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Got to the bottom of this one. This was a case of mistaken identity...of sorts. What was happening was the current session was being invalidated by someone logging in with the same account on a different mobile device. The server then invalidated the prior session. All is well, but rather than returning a 401, they returned a 301, triggering an ClientProtocolException in the HTTPClient. Doh. A wasted day. Thanks for the help everyone!